# How to mock the CreateResponse<T> extension method on HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, mocking

I'm using ASP.Net MVC 4 RC's ApiController and I'm trying to unit test a GET method.

This method uses the `CreateResponse<T>` method that's on the `HttpRequestMessage`, but I've no idea how to mock this or to make it function correctly.

The method's body contains this:

```
MediaTypeHeaderValue header = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(versionedSmartBlock.ContentType);
var response = Request.CreateResponse<SmartBlock>(
    HttpStatusCode.OK, versionedSmartBlock, header);
```

Within my unit test, I create an empty `HttpRequestMessage`:

```
CallsController api = new CallsController(
    managerMock.Object, config, adapterFactoryMock.Object);
api.Request = new HttpRequestMessage(
    HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost/Initiate?ern=%2B44123456789");    
var response = api.Get("+44123456789", null);
```

But it just generates an `InvalidOperationException`:

> The request does not have an associated configuration object or the
>   provided configuration was null.

Has anyone got any pointers on how I can configure the `HttpRequestMessage` so that the `CreateResponse` method actually does its job?

Comment: This looks like it's addressing the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868673/asp-net-webapi-unit-testing-with-request-createresponse

Answer (score 159, accepted):

This was solved by specifying an empty configuration:

```
request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new HttpConfiguration());
```

I got the answer to that from here

[ASP.NET WebApi unit testing with Request.CreateResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868673/asp-net-webapi-unit-testing-with-request-createresponse)

Answer (score 0):

WebAPI 1 with VB here!

I managed to hybrid responses from your link above to get this to work as simple as this:

```
Dim request As HttpRequestMessage = New HttpRequestMessage()
Return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, myCustomClassObject, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
```

Just posting in case it helps anyone.