# How should an API controller be tested now when HttpResponseMessage is created from the request?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Now when the constructor to create a response with `HttpResponseMessage<T>` and content is gone how should you do it if you want to test your controller? `Request.CreateResponse<T>` should be used instead and that is like such:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
{
    // Do Something
    var response = Request.CreateResponse<SomeType>(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, someObject);
    return response;
}
```

Now to test a controller like this I have to stub the `Request` object since that is a property on the base class and I should use it to create the response, but that is not something I like and wonder if I can do it some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, if you don't need to modify HttpResponseMessage, avoid to use it in ApiController, this will make your code simpler:

```
public SomeType Post()
{
     // Do Something
     return someObject;
}
```

In case it cannot be avoided, here is your answer:

[ASP.NET WebApi unit testing with Request.CreateResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868673/asp-net-webapi-unit-testing-with-request-createresponse)

Comment: I guess you have the most correct answer, but I don't like it. The change Microsoft has done with the API makes it less testable if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't return an `HttpResponseMessage` then WebApi will call a `MediaTypeFormatter` for you to write the result to the response stream (i.e. it will use a `MediaTypeFormatter` to create an `HttpResponseMessage` for you). Many of the default implementations will do something similar to what you have above. Easiest solution is to return `SomeType` from your function and then utilize one of the built-in `MediaTypeFormatter`s to do the conversion. You can test both solutions in isolation and together.

Comment: I think you are wrong, how will you control the http status code with your approach? The status code is not something you should control from the `MediaTypeFormatter`.

Comment: If you are concerned about returning various status codes (e.g. a 201) you can choose to change `SomeType` to be wrapped in a `Created<SomeType>` object or something. You also have the option of an ActionFilter for that sort of work. Obviously each implementation is different and this won't work for everything...

Comment: But that was the purpose of `HttpResponseMessage<T>`, which they now removed. Doing what you suggest feels like working against the framework rather than with the framework.